# Extra unicodes printed when trying to print emojis in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, unicode

When I try to print an emoji like so:

```
print("Incomplete frame ⚠️")
```

Sometimes it is printed in the debugger as:

```
Incomplete frame ⚠⚠\357️
```

The same goes for this one:

```
print("Frame not ready  ")
```

Which is sometimes (but not always!) displayed:

```
Frame not ready  \360\237\222
```

Or, even worse, like

```
Frame not ready  \360\237\360\237\360\237\222
```

Why is this happening? How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to Convert Unicode string into attributed string, use this below **String extension**

```
extension String
    func UnicodeToAttributed() -> NSAttributedString? {
        do {

            let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
            if let d = data {
                let str = try NSAttributedString(data: d,
                                                 options: [ 
                           NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], 
                                                 documentAttributes: nil)
                return str
            }
        } catch {
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

Comment: Nothing; in fact, each string is now followed by `NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x105e27cd0> font-family: \".SFUIText\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
}`

Comment: NSLog() doesn't have this issue. It does print out timestamps, which I could do without, but at least now the emojis line up nicely

Comment: @PhilipS Give me your unicode so that i will try here.